# Can't use jQuery .eq() to target video.js UI controls in Chrome and IE10

Tags: jquery, drupal, video.js

I have a jQuery snippet I'm trying to use as a hack to fix the known bug in the videojs plugin (I'm trying to make subtitles display by default, however, they only seem to work when the language is selected from the list in the videojs player).

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.PixtureReloaded = {
        attach: function() {
            $("li.vjs-menu-item").eq(1).trigger('click');
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This works in Firefox but not IE10 or Chrome, and I'm not sure why. Using Chrome's developer tools, it looks like the element and class I'm targeting is added to the DOM, but when I try in IE and Chrome to log the value of

```
$("li.vjs-menu-item").eq(1).text
```

I get nothing.

Thank in advance for any ideas or comments!

Matt

Comment: is `$('li.vjs-menu-item')` populated with the elements?

Comment: `eq()` uses a zero-based index.. are you intending to target the second element?

Comment: `console.log($("li.vjs-menu-item").eq(1).length)`

Comment: @Jason P I am targeting the second element

Comment: @ Dan Heberden $('li.vjs-menu-item') is populated with the elements.

Comment: I would try triggering the click event on the native element. replace `.eq` with `.get`, then use `.click()` rather than `.trigger()`. `$("li.vjs-menu-item").get(1).click();`

Comment: @Kevin B Thanks, tried it, but still no joy...